# I took an input as string with scanf() but output with cout.why did my program terminate?

Tags: string, scanf

I took an  input as string with scanf() but output with cout.My program terminated.But if I  use printf() instead of cout it works.Can anybody tell me about this ?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string s;
scanf("%s",s);
cout <<s<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You've not provided sufficient code that will allow us to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) uses c-string (char arrays).
Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead.

Comment: printf and scanf both use c-strings. The C++ tools using the string class will not work with old C tools for c-strings.